# Unpickle big python object through subprocess

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, pickle

How can you pass and unpickle large objects through a subprocess.  So my example below works for small object (dictionary), but stops working if it has large data in it:

Heres my working sample:

return_pickle.py

```
import pickle
import io
import sys

NUMS = 10
    
sample_obj = {'a':1, 'b': [x for x in range(NUMS)]}
d = pickle.dumps(sample_obj)
sys.stdout = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdout.detach(), encoding='latin-1')
print(d.decode('latin-1'), end='', flush=True)
```

unpickle.py

```
import subprocess
import pickle

proc = subprocess.Popen(["python", "return_pickle.py"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

output, err = proc.communicate()
data = pickle.loads(output)
print(data)
```

So the above works fine as is, but if I change `NUMS` to `100` it errors out with `_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x0a'.` or if I change sample_obj to have a list of dictionaries, if the list is big I will get the same error.  How do I get around this?

I am using Python 3.7 and on a Windows 10 machine

Comment: Pickled data is inherently binary.  Applying any sort of text encoding to it will most likely destroy it.

Comment: So theres no way for me to pass large objects from a subprocess?  Unless I write it to a file, and the main script just reads it from there?

Comment: No, just don't encode it in latin-1

Comment: "latin-1" doesn't change any bytes - it's a "do-nothing" encoding. That's not the problem here - see my answer for what it (it's specific to text mode on Windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me on a windows machine if you don't stringify the result and instead post it directly to the stdout buffer:

`return_pickle.py`

```
import pickle, sys

sample_obj = {'a':1, 'b': [x for x in range(100)]}
sys.stdout.buffer.write(pickle.dumps(sample_obj))
```

```
import subprocess, pickle

proc = subprocess.Popen(
    ["python", "return_pickle.py"],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,
)

output, _ = proc.communicate()
print(pickle.loads(output))
```

Comment: Probably the cleanest if determined to pursue this approach, but note the docs: "
The underlying binary buffer (a BufferedIOBase instance) that TextIOBase deals with. This is not part of the TextIOBase API and may not exist in some implementations." Better to use a portable way.

Comment: Interesting, today I learned. I've just always used it when needed and didn't consider it wasn't part of the standard APIs.

Answer (score 2):

It will work if you add `protocol=0` to your `dumps()` call, but this is horribly convoluted.  Proto 0 is "text mode", and is inefficient in many ways higher pickle protocols improved on, but on Windows it can make a huge difference.

The size of the objects doesn't really matter.  Your example would fail if you just set `NUMS` to 11.  What happens: if an element in the list happens to be 10, pickle produces an "opcode" having a byte with value 10.  But `chr(10) == '\n'`, and in text mode output on Windows the implementation says "oh, a newline! I have to change that to carriage-return + newline instead".

So what *was* a single 10 byte in the original pickle stream gets corrupted to a 13 (`\r`)  byte followed by a 10 (`\n`) byte. 13 ends up getting put into the list the unpickler is building, and then the leftover 10 makes no sense at all in context. That's the source of the "Invalid load key, '\x0a'" message - `0x0a == 10`.

Of course there are many other ways a byte with value 10 *could* end up in the pickle stream, but if you write in text mode they'll all get corrupted similarly on Windows.

There are straightforward, platform-independent ways to do this with binary pickles, all easier than trying to fool stdout into being something it wasn't intended to be.  Easiest:  `pickle.dump(obj, f)` to a file opened in binary write mode on one end, then simply `pickle.load(f)` on the other end for the same file opened for binary mode reading on the other end.

### Gilding the lily ;-)

Inspired by @flakes, here's a different way to trick stdout into using binary mode, but relying only on documented portable APIs:

```
import os, sys, pickle
...
with os.fdopen(sys.stdout.fileno(), "wb", closefd=False) as stdout:
    pickle.dump(sample_obj, stdout)
```

### Using an anonymous OS-level pipe

To show a possible complication, here's much the same thing using `os.pipe()`. This gets annoying, because the OS pipe ends are "file descriptors" on Unix-y systems, but really "handles" on Windows. So the code you need depends on the platform you're using. I'll just cater to Windows here.

writepik.py, invoked by readpik.py:

```
import os, pickle, msvcrt, sys

data = {"d": 1, "L": list(range(50000))}

h = int(sys.argv[1])
d = msvcrt.open_osfhandle(h, 0)
with os.fdopen(d, "wb") as dest:
    pickle.dump(data, dest)
```

So it's passed an integer "handle" on the command line, which it has to change into a "file descriptor", which is then passed to `fdopen()` to create a file object long enough to dump the pickle.

readpik.py:

```
import os, pickle, msvcrt, subprocess

r, w = os.pipe()
h = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(w)
os.set_handle_inheritable(h, True)
proc = subprocess.Popen(["py", "writepik.py", str(h)], close_fds=False)
os.close(w)
with os.fdopen(r, "rb") as src:
    data = pickle.load(src)
print(data)
```

So that's somewhat the reverse. `os.pipe()` returns "file descriptors", but for a subprocess to properly inherit an open Windows handle we have to make the handle inheritable instead of the file descriptor.  So we get the numeric "handle" via `get_osfhandle(w)` long enough to mark it inheritable and plug its value into the command line for writepik.py.

It's not really hard, but the dance is delicate and so easy to get wrong.

Comment: I'm curious why you say that stdout pipe isn't intended for binary data? It's pretty common to use pipes for this in a lot of programs, say apps like `dd` or `tar`

Comment: Then you're not running on WIndows. This question, and my answer, are specific to Windows.- so I just added the "windows" tag.

Comment: No. `-u` controls buffering, not text-vs-binary mode. If you actually tried your suggestions on Windows, you would see for yourself that they don't help.

Comment: I'm kind of hesitant to always suggest the file solution just because you don't always have the disk space available for it- say it could be an arbitrary large binary stream (which generally I would use fifos for on most *nix systems).

Comment: Then the OP can say so, and get pointed to, e.g., sockets, or interprocess pipes, or ...

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  When would it be better to use sockets or interprocess pipes (do you mean multiprocess and using queues?)

Comment: I personally never would, unless the project required interprocess communication for more than just this much. It adds overheads and complications. Writing/reading  binary files is dead easy and dead obvious.

Comment: FYI, at the bottom I added code showing how to do this with a pipe on Windows.